# Error in PHP code to construct URL

Tags: php, url

I need to fix this URL redirect in header

```
$siteurl = http://myfirstsite.com
$siteurl2 = http://mysecondsite.com

<a href="<?php echo if (strstr ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "hus")) {
    echo $siteurl;
} else {
    echo $siteurl2;
}."/".ereg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.php"; ?>">
```

It throws an error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't use ereg functions. They're deprecated. Use the preg functions instead.

```
preg_replace('/ /', '-', ...);
```

Beyond that, the fix is trivial:

```
if (...) {
   header('Location: ' . $siteurl . preg_replace(...));
} else {
   header('Location: ' . $siteurl2 . preg_replace(...));
}
```

Comment: i use like this `<a href="<?php if (strstr ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "hus")) {
   header('Location: ' . $siteurl . preg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.php"));
} else {
   header('Location: ' . $siteurl2 . preg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.php"));
}
?>">`

Comment: preg requires delimiters around the regex. `'/ /'`, not `" "` as you have.

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating against the braces of an if block `{}`.  Instead, `echo`:

```
<a href="<?php echo if (strstr ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "hus")) {
    echo $siteurl;
} else {
    echo $siteurl2;
}
echo "/".ereg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.php"; 
?>">
```